# Golang optional json fields

Tags: json, go

In Python I do like this to make dict and return in json:

```
class Thing:
    id = 1
    name = 'name'
    user = User()
    obj = Obj()
    upd = time
    def to_dict(this, user=False, obj=False):
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'name': self.name,
            'upd': self.upd.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
            'user': self.user.to_dict() if opt else None,
            'obj': self.obj.to_dict() if obj else None,
        }
```

and then `json.dumps(thing.to_dict(**opts))`. `opts` goes from web request.
Ofcourse in real project the fields a lot more. And some fields should be either in dict or not.

Is any solution to don't make different structs only for json response? Or add optional to `MarshalJSON()`

Comment: Sounds like you're asking about the [`omitempty` struct field tag](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Marshal).

Comment: No no. I need to make sctruct object first and then do marshal.

Comment: Or I can change the omitempty (on/off) option programmatically?

Comment: Prepare your JSON object in a `map[string]interface{}` then: don't add map entries for items you don't want to appear in the marshaled JSON.